# Apache POI error when running as a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, apache-poi

I have a program that runs in `Eclipse` fine, but when exported into a `jar` file it gives me this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/Encryp
tedDocumentException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I have added the `apache` `poi` `jar` files to my built path so I am unsure why it cannot find that `EncryptedCocumentException` class.

Comment: I have tried an older version of the api, 3.9, and a different test program with the same results.  Im running on an Windows XP machine and my eclipse version is  Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).  My main program is using apachi-poi version 3.12.

Comment: Did you make sure that all the Apache POI jars were present on your classpath at *runtime* as well as at compile time?

Comment: Yes, in eclipse all the jars are listed and selected in the `build path` under `libraries` and `order and export`.

Comment: The word `build` in there should be your clue that it's only fixed the build time issue! You need to make sure you also have the jars available at runtime on your classpath, which is normally a very different step